# How to create function that moves screen to diff. full screen divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

the site basically looks like this

`---------------------------------------------------
|    0           |    Clients    |   0           |`

`---------------------------------------------------
|    Services    |    0          |    About      |`

`---------------------------------------------------
|     0          |   Home        |   0           |`
 
`---------------------------------------------------
|     Price      |   0           |   Portfolio   |`
 
`---------------------------------------------------
|     0          |    Contact    |   0           |`
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------

where each division takes up the entire screen and the 0 is plain white unused div.
First I need to fix the screen with no scroll bars.
How do I make

-a function that takes the screen to "Home" as the site loads(onload)?

-a function that takes the screen(setting transition)  to the particular divisions when the respective navigation option(which will be fixed up top) is clicked?

Regarding CSS, I dont know what(body or wrapper) has to be set to 300%x500%(entire page) and how to implement the function. 
All using html, css, and pure javascript.

I understand the screen on focus needs to be moved by changing the margins but I failed in doing so. I started off a bit but obviously am completely stuck. Please help.

Comment: that would be on click(hoping I clearly understand your comment). but I want it to happen onLoad

Comment: give style to body{ overflow:hidden !important; } but what have you tried already? we're not hear that you can just say what you want and somebody codes it for you ;p

Comment: :) yes I understand. I've made the model(html&css)...tried implementing js..it didnt work. and thank you...oveflow:hidden solved the fixing screen part :)

Comment: after overflow:hidden I'm changing body margin(top and left) in negative to get the screen on "home". but this only works in pixels. It might get a wierd display on other laptops. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Few hints:

CSS:

```
body { width:300%; height:500%; overflow:hidden; }
```

JS:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
//set "home" in the center of page
window.onload = function () {
    x.style.marginLeft = "homeXposition";
    x.style.marginTop = "homeYposition";
}
// function for "take me to some section"
// wh defines element
function goSomewhere(wh) {
    switch(wh){
case about:
    x.style.marginLeft = "aboutXposition";
    x.style.marginTop = "aboutYposition";
    break;
case medjed:
    x.style.marginLeft = "medjedXposition";
    x.style.marginTop = "medjedYposition";
    break;
.......................
default:
    ...........
    }
}
```

Edit:
This is for you if all your sections have size of the screen.

```
var mrdalo = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

function moveYourBody (myb) {
    switch myb {
        case cl: //Clients
            mrdalo.style.marginLeft = "100%";
            mrdalo.style.marginTop = "0";
            break;
        case se: //Services
            mrdalo.style.marginLeft = "0";
            mrdalo.style.marginTop = "100%";
            break;
        case ab: //About
            mrdalo.style.marginLeft = "200%";
            mrdalo.style.marginTop = "100%";
            break;
        case pr: //Price
            mrdalo.style.marginLeft = "0";
            mrdalo.style.marginTop = "300%";
            break;
        case po: //Portfolio
            mrdalo.style.marginLeft = "200%";
            mrdalo.style.marginTop = "300%";
            break;
        case co: //Contacts
            mrdalo.style.marginLeft = "100%";
            mrdalo.style.marginTop = "400%";
            break;
        default: //Home
            mrdalo.style.marginLeft = "100%";
            mrdalo.style.marginTop = "200%";
            break;
    }
}

Comment: is the positioning in pixels? I need this to work on other PCs. Can it be done in percentage?

Comment: You can use % as well ;)

Comment: I copy pasted the first function, setting marginLeft ="-200%" and marginTop="-300%" and I got this :- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined 001.js:4 window.onload

Comment: Have you forgot var x = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] ?

Comment: I've edited code. Notice that starting point of absolute position calculating inside a page is top left corner. All you need to do now is to add this function to onclick event or directly into link.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to animate across the page, traversing over sections? If I went from `Clients` to `Contact`, would I pass over `Home`?

Here's a demo of that: http://codepen.io/Oka/pen/jEaPJb, using lots of `position: absolute;`.

The important JS:

```
var wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap'),
    links = document.querySelectorAll('.sp');

function Page(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

Page.prototype.display = function () {
  wrap.style.left = '-' + this.x;
  wrap.style.top = '-' + this.y;
}


Pages = {
  'clients': new Page('100%', '0'),
  'services': new Page('0', '100%'),
  'about': new Page('200%', '100%'),
  'price': new Page('0', '300%'),
  'portfolio': new Page('200%', '300%'),
  'contacts': new Page('100%', '400%'),
  'home': new Page('100%', '200%')
}

for (var n = 0; n < links.length; n += 1) {
  links[n].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var des = this.getAttribute('href');

    Pages[des].display();
  });
}

Pages.home.display();
```

---

If not this, I have a tiny framework that can do something *similar* to what you've described, but not exactly.

Pages.js - https://github.com/Oka-/pages

The full docs are here http://pages.oka.io/, or in the repo README.

It's *almost* pure JavaScript, with a dependency on [Velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) for most of the leg work. Downside is that it's IE 9+.

Upside is, Velocity has really good performance.

## [Here's a demo](http://codepen.io/Oka/full/QwOwzZ/)

Pages uses full page divs, and swaps them around as you change the page with special anchor links.

The API is basic, here's the example of the method that creates the document with no animations:

```
Pages.build({
  animation: 'none',
  lock: 0,
  enableKeys: false
});
```

Hope it can help you out, or at least steer you in the right direction for your own implementation.

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to vote on/pick answers if they help! @JwalaJosePTL

Comment: @Collin Hall-Coates :D lol sure. I will as soon as I'm allowed.